# How to use create method in Active Record Query in a has many through relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have reviews ,users and airlines this is how to association is set up

```
class Airline < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :reviews
    has_many :users,through: :reviews
end

class Review < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :airline

 

end

class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_secure_password
    has_many :reviews
    has_many :airlines,through: :reviews 
end
```

I want to do create method in my console... where I want to create a review by a particular user associated with a particular airline
I know i can grab my user like this

```
u1=User.find_by_name("Max")
r1=u1.reviews.create("")
```

but how can I associate the airline I know there is something "where". I don't no how to write that command.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you just need to create the review:

```
u = User.find_by(name: 'Max')
a = Airline.find_by(name: 'Poop Airlines')
r = Review.create(review: 'This airline smells.', user: u, airline: a)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the right track. Since a review is created by a user for an airline, a review needs both user_id and airline_id.

In your code you have grabbed the user, now get the airline for which you want to create a record and then create a review

```
u1=User.find_by_name("Max")
a1 = Airline.find_by_name("Airline name")
r1=u1.reviews.create(review_column_name: "", airline: a1) //<replace review_column_name> to whatever your column name in db
```